# React Native Form - Check if number has a decimal point issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a basic form within a React Native view - as a basic summary it collects van mileage used in calculations at a later date.  The form input uses a numeric keyboard, both fields are required and validated.  I'd like to validate the number has been entered and that the user hasn't used a decimal point.

For background - heres a shot of the form:

[image]

each field is created using a RN TextInput, both are identical bar the state names - code as follows -

```
<View style={CheckInStyles.textBlock}>
          <Text style={CheckInStyles.introTxt}>
            3. End Mileage.<Text style={CheckInStyles.errorStyle}> * </Text>
          </Text>
          <Text style={CheckInStyles.introTxtOr}>
            (Please enter mileage upon completing your journey).
          </Text>
        </View>
        <View style={formStyles.textInputBlock}>
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Enter Vehicle END Mileage"
            style={formStyles.textInputText}
            value={this.state.endMileage}
            autoCorrect={false}
            returnKeyType="done"
            keyboardType="numeric"
            onSubmitEditing={Keyboard.dismiss}
            onChangeText={text => this.setState({endMileage: text})}
          />
        </View>
```

the initial state is numeric - code below:

```
constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        startMileage:0,
        endMileage:0,
      }
  }
```

on validation I have the following code -

```
    if (this.state.startMileage && this.state.endMileage && this.state.tripReason && Number.isInteger(this.state.startMileage) && Number.isInteger(this.state.endMileage)) {
        
        return true
        
       }
       else {
        return false;
       }
```

The part I need help understanding is the number / decimal point check - i'm using

```
Number.isInteger()
```

If I use a direct number ie:

```
Number.isInteger(3.3)
```

the result is false - as expected

```
Number.isInteger(3)
```

the result is true as expected

If **however** I use the **state numeric value** -

```
Number.isInteger(this.state.endMileage))
```

regardless of whether the value is a whole or contains a decimal point - **the results is always false.**

Is this because the state input is using a text input and the value is converted to a string? Can anyone advise a solution / explanation?  Thanks.

Comment: "Is this because the state input is using a text input?" Yes, it is exactly this. `Number.isInteger(value)` [will always return false if the value is not a number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger). You could look into `Number.parseFloat`, and possibly pass `keyboardType="number-pad"` rather than `numeric`.

Comment: @motto Used both your suggestions - ie parsefloat the string then the isInteger - worked a treat - if you would like a correct answer - the key part for me was the understanding that the textinput always converts input to string - thanks for this.   just add below and i'll give you a tick.  cheers.  Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Is this because the state input is using a text input?" Yes, it is exactly this.

Number.isInteger(value) [will always return false if the value is not a number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger).

You could look into [Number.parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseFloat), and possibly pass [keyboardType="number-pad"](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#keyboardtype) rather than numeric.